# RedisException php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: php, laravel, redis, queue

I have Redis and php-redis extension installed but whenever I wanna use a queue in Laravel I just get the error below

```
RedisException
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Comment: Have done changes in .env file  and any pacakge you have install for this ?

Comment: Yes, I've edited my .env file

Comment: Please check you have done these changes as below?  By adding this line in .env file``QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis <---change.  REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1 REDIS_PASSWORD=null REDIS_PORT=6379 REDIS_CLIENT = predis <---Add this line `` Then run this command:- ``php artisan config:cache``

Comment: With `REDIS_CLIENT=predis` I get the following error: ` PHP Error:  Class "Predis\Client" not found in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connectors/PredisConnector.php on line 30` How do I fix it?

Comment: With the default value `REDIS_CLIENT=phpredis`,  I'm getting the following error: `php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for redis failed: Temporary failure in name resolution`. How do I fix it?

Comment: @Pathros You should install predis - `composer require predis/predis`

Answer (score 0):

`docker-compose restart redis` (or the same name wich you gived your redis-server)

Comment: What if the asker is not using docker?

Comment: this is not a proper solution lol. I am using redis in aws elasticcache

Answer (score 0):

in public php artisan passport:keys

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).